# Who determines the MediaInfo stream type?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I started using the `VideoCastManager.isRemoteStreamLive()` method on the CCL but I just realized it always returns false. That method seems to depend on `info.getStreamType()` so I'm wondering who should be setting that type to live stream? is there maybe a way to do this on the receiver end?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you send the media item (MediaInfo) to the receiver for loading and layback from your sender, can't you set the stream type in your sender?

Comment: No my sender doesn't have any easy way to know if the user chose a normal video or a live stream.

Comment: How would your receiver know?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a video expert but I figured the receiver is the only one that is actually opening the stream and looking at it.

Comment: If you are writing your own receiver, you need to find out if it is live or not; there is no magic that would determine that for you automagically. From your sender, you are pointing at a media so I am not sure why you wouldn't have that information at that point but if you don't, then you need to find a way on the receiver or sender to decide on that and then manually set the stream type; none of the Cast SDKs would do that for you.

Comment: I guess I'll have to investigate how to do that on the receiver end. Do the media duration and current player position hin at it being a live stream? I haven't verified this is try but I think I'm getting 0 back for those right now on live streams.

Comment: just try it...  .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)  that code in the MI.builder and then see if it works.

Comment: My issue isn't setting the stream type but rather figuring out the stream type.

Answer (score 1):

Are these your streams? If so, the best option is to put something into the metadata or a track that indicates it's a live stream. If that's not possible, there are some "sniffing" strategies that may or may not be useful.

First of all, the spec for the HTML5 video element states that if the bounds of a video (i.e. duration) cannot be determined, then the getDuration method should return infinity (the javascript constant is equal to Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY). This doesn't always mean that the video is streaming (there may be problems with the response's content-length header, for example), but it is possibly your best option -- have your receiver, once the metadata is loaded, call getDuration and see what's returned.

You could also have your receiver look at the source (the currentSrc attribute of the video's metadata) -- a lot of live streams are adaptive bitrate streams, and so would be represented in the video element as .m3u8 sources.

But these are just ways to make educated guesses; as Ali noted in one of his comments, there is no programmatic way for the client (whether through native javascript APIs or the Chromecast APIs) to determine that a stream is a live stream.

Comment: The streams aren't mine. Thank you for all that info.